# Correct image size at the source or hardocing the dp size in layout

Tags: android, android-layout

When you create your xml layout and say you load imageview or a button with a background from a drawable image. Then do you design the orginal drawable image so that it's size will look what you want on screen when using "wrap content"? Or do you just grab whatever size the image is and resize the widget that is using the image by putting something like in the xml

> android:width ="100dp"   android:height="100dp"

Comment: Can you explain what you mean in a different way? Are you wondering about how an ImageView fits an image to its layout?

Answer (score 0):

This best way I can suggest you is to get you image designed in proper resolution and put it in appropriate drawable folder. Let's say you are targeted highest resolution is 1080x1920, then get your screen designed in this resolution and slice the image in actual resolution and paste it in "drawable-xxhdpi" folder. It'll work for your targeted screen size and for all other resolutions smaller than the targets resolution.

Comment: So is this better than setting the actual size you want by specifiying hardcoded numbers?

Comment: Yeah by setting the hard coded numbers you may face responsiveness issues on different screens resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

In situations like this, it's better to specify the dimensions of the view.

When you set a drawable as a background to a `View`, it automatically takes up the size of that `View`.
Here's an example:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background" />
```

The background will be the image named `background.png`/`background.xml` in your drawable folder, and no matter the size, it will take up the size of the `TextView`, which is 400dp long and 100dp tall.

Comment: You miss understood my question. I am asking if it is better to create an image with the desired size and use it with wrap_content, or to set the size we want using specified hardcoded values for width and height

Comment: Specify the values for width and height in your layout. It's a better choice since the background will automatically adapt and it scales on higher DPI devices.

Comment: putting wrap_content will do the same I believe as the image px will be scaled up or down